# Consider the autonomous ODE: $y^{'} = X(y)$. Let $X \in C^1(\mathcal U_X)$ and $y(t_1) = y(t_2)$ for $t_1 < t_2$. Show $y$ is constant?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the autonomous ODE: $y^{'} = X(y)$ (doesn't depend on $t$) defined on $\mathcal U_X \subset \mathbb R$. Let $X \in C^1(\mathcal U_X)$ and suppose $y(t_1) = y(t_2)$ for $t_1 < t_2$, where $(I,y)$ is a solution.

I want to prove that $y$ is a constant solution. A hint is given that I should apply Rolle's theorem and the fact maximal solutions are always defined on an open interval and a solution is either maximal or a restriction thereof.

I see that there must exist $c \in (t_1, t_2)$ such that $y^{'}(c) = 0 = X(y(c))$ by Rolle's theorem.

Also, since $X$ has continuous $y$-derivatives, a maximal solution for an IVP must be unique and non-crossing ?

How can I use the above in proving that $y$ must be constant ?

Also if $\mathcal U_X \subset \mathbb R^n$, where $n > 1$, why must $I =  \mathbb R$ and $y$ periodic with period $t_2 - t_1$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, $y(t)=c$ is a solution. If $y(t_1)\ne c$, you would have two different solutions on $(t_1,c)$.

Comment: I just figured that out $5$ minutes ago. Can you give any input on the second part ?

Comment: Suppose the solution with $y(t_1)=y(t_2)$ is not constant. Without loss of generality we may assume that $y$ attains its maximum at a point $c\in(t_1,t_2)$. Then $y'(c)=0$. Let $z(t)=c$. $z$ is a solution, and $y(c)=z(c)$. By uniqueness, $y\equiv z$.